# I get "IndexOutOfBounds" in my Comets vs Spaceship Game

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I began developing a "Spaceship vs Comets" style game last week and now I have come to a stop.

The purpose of the game is to shoot the comets before they pass your ship. You make the comets explode by firing at them. Simple idea!

However, sometimes when I play I get the **"IndexOutOfBounds" error**. *It almost always appears when I haven't fired for a while (The size of my shots ArrayList is 0) and when I then fire and it collides it crashes.*

So I have some kind of error in my code, but I really can't see it. I now hope that one of you might see why this accurs and save me from further "IndexOutOfBounds" errors! :)

Here is the part of the code that fails, including the functions that I use to move the comets and shots:

**GAME CLASS**

```
    if(!Game.player.getShots().isEmpty() && !comet.getComets().isEmpty()) { //Om de är tomma så ignorera

        for(int x = 0; x < Game.player.getShots().size(); x++) {    //Shots X

            if(!comet.getComets().isEmpty() && !comet.getComets().isEmpty()) {



                for(int y = 0; y < comet.getComets().size(); y++) {     //Comets Y

                    if(comet.getComets().get(y).intersects(Game.player.getShots().get(x)) && !comet.getComets().isEmpty() && !Game.player.getShots().isEmpty()) {   
    //the for loop above is the line that won't compile sometimes

                        comet.getComets().remove(y);
                        Game.player.getShots().remove(x);   

                        score++;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }

    //Comet spawn timer
    comet.addComets();

    //Move the comets and shots!
    Game.player.moveShots();
    comet.moveComets();
    repaint();
```

**COMET CLASS**

```
public ArrayList<Rectangle> getComets() {

    return comets;
}

public void moveComets() {
    if(!comets.isEmpty()) {

        for(int x = 0; x < comets.size(); x++) {

            comets.get(x).x -= cometSpeed;
        }
    }

}
```

**PLAYER CLASS (Shots are in this class)**

```
public void fire() {


    shots.add(new Rectangle(x + player.width, y + 23, shotWidth,shotHeight));
}
public ArrayList<Rectangle> getShots() {

    return shots;

}

public void moveShots() {
    if(!shots.isEmpty()) {
        for(int x = 0; x < shots.size(); x++) {

            shots.get(x).x += fireSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

*Keep in mind that comets and shots are both "ArrayList out of the object Rectangle"*

**I will provide screenshots of error and a picture of the game below!**

[image: Picture of the GUI]

[image: Picture of the error in console]

The error line is marked in the code above, the if statement should block it from crashing (I thought).

Thanks in advance! All help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Check line 128 of your Game class, that's where it happens. debug your code and see what goes wrong.

Comment: Already done that, I cant figure it out.. I check if they are empty or not on that line so it shouldn't be able to pass

Comment: the Bool statements at the if are commonly evaluated from left to right, you should check if empty at the left of the intersect

Comment: I will try that @BrunoLoops thanks!

Comment: Heya mate, a suggestion to help with code organization... you may want to have all your objects on the screen that move/collide inherit from an `GameObject` interface that has a `update()` method which needs implemented. Then you can self contain in each object it's own movement updating and collision checking. From there, in your main Game loop you just have to run through all your `GameObject` sub-classes and call the `update()` method. Could help you with debugging and reducing nested looping like in your `Game` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the order at the if statement to avoid it from evaluate one part of it.
You should change your condition to:

`if( x < Game.player.getShots().size() && comet.getComets().get(y).intersects(Game.player.getShots().get(x))) {`

That's because you're removing a shot and inside the comets for when the shoot is removed at the next comet iteration it will throw `IndexOutOfBounds` as the array no longer have the shot you're checking at the if, so you'll need to check again for the x existing on shots.
You can also do it at the for, you check for both conditions and you let the intersect as only check at the if.

A better performance if would be:

```
if(!Game.player.getShots().isEmpty() || !comet.getComets().isEmpty()) { 
//if one of them is empty, won't be intersections

        for(int x = 0; x < Game.player.getShots().size(); x++) {    //Shots X
                for(int y = 0; y < comet.getComets().size() && x < Game.player.getShots().size(); y++) {
 //Comets Y only if the shoot still available

                    if(comet.getComets().get(y).intersects(Game.player.getShots().get(x))) {   
    //the for loop above is the line that won't compile sometimes

                        comet.getComets().remove(y);
                        Game.player.getShots().remove(x);   

                        score++;
                        y = 0; // if you don't set the y = 0 the next shoot (as you removed the x, getShots.get(x) would be the x + 1 shoot) will only evaluate for the comets after y, won't evaluate the firsts comets at the array.
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Yep that fixed it! I didn't think of that. I will grab a pen and paper next time and debug it that way when facing this issue another time! Thanks @BrunoLoops

Answer (score 2):

Try to adjust here `if(!comet.getComets().isEmpty() && !comet.getComets().isEmpty())`. You are checking for comet array twice.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I fixed the issue, it didn't work! Thanks anyway for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Is this code multithreaded?
I am also wondering why you are verifying `comet.getComets().isEmpty()` so many times.

My guess is that you are manipulating the `ArrayList` in some other part of your code. Reason I think this is because you are checking the size of the list multiple times and because within the for loop you are only deleting in the end, so that should not be the problem.

For instance if you run this method at two threads at the same time, the ArrayList can be checked at one point, but can reduce after checking the size. then when for instance the size was 10, but became 9, but you still try to delete x with value 10, you will get the out of bounds error.

Comment: I think it uses 1 Thread, don't know how to check. I check if it's empty so many times because I thought there was a gap somewhere. I can remove some of those if statements if I want to. The issue was what BrunoLoops said earlier